# PostgreSQL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections, too many clients already

Tags: postgresql, scalability

We have web application using [Golang](http://golang.org), [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org), and [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) (adapter, connection pooler), that each request requires 1 to 8 queries, sometimes 1 transaction with 5-8 select and 5-8 insert queries.

We already set our PostgreSQL's `max_connections` from 1024, then 4096, but it start swapping, so we reduce them back to 64 (this is the limit before swapping).

Our RAM is 2GB, we configure the PostgreSQL's `working_mem` to 16MB and `temp_buffers` to 8MB, `shared_buffers` to 800MB, `effective_cache_size`                to 1536MB (this configuration doesn't swap at all).

There are about 18 request per second everyday at 00:00 to 02:35, and there's about 8 errors per second, at that point only 10 transaction per hours that succeed, others are failed, with error message either:

- remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
- too many clients already

How to overcome this problem other than caching the read-only page (since the page can be updated about 10 times per minutes) or upgrading the machine?

Comment: `max_connections = 1024` is way too much for such a small server.

Answer (score 5):

`max_connections = 1024` ?! You need a connection pool.

Use PgBouncer in transaction-pooling mode if your app doesn't support built-in pooling.

You're running PostgreSQL on a tiny toy server. Keep the active connection count low and queue work up in series.

High `max_connections` introduces significant inefficiency, and having lots of actively working connections adds more.

Comment: `sqlx` have connection pooling. `http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#connectionPool`

Comment: @Kokizzu Then limit your pool size to slightly below your PostgreSQL `max_connections`.

Comment: _High `max_connections` introduces significant inefficiency_ - what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: @dezso Pg does some work that scales linearly with the size of max_connections, even if there aren't any active workers. Compare a pgbench with 100 clients on 100 max_connections to the same pgbench with 1000 max_connections.

Comment: @CraigRinger is there somewhere a mailing list or blog post describing these?  or the only way is to go and check the source?

Comment: @dezso AFAIK source only. Anything that scans PGPROC potentially, though reuse of the lower end of the array means things that stop scanning once they find one match are much less than O(n). Perf is useful too, with userspace probes. It's changed version-to-version too thanks to scalability improvements.